# How to reconfigure the ip addresses of all nodes after migrating networks

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Running 2 node Cassandra 3.11.4-1 cluster

Shutdown the servers, migrated to a different network and reipped them on a different name.

how do we reconfigure the cassandra application/cluster to work on the new ips (192.168.1.x)
old ip (192.168.0.x)

The cassandra.yaml is using DNS, so the local ip's have auto updated
the remote node's are still showing the old ips are aren't updating.

how do i update the ips so the cluster reconnects

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                                  Rack
UN  192.168.1.5  3.63 GiB   256          100.0%            null                                      rack1
?N  192.168.0.6   ?          256          100.0%            null                                     rack1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use hostnames in your configuration. Use the IP addresses instead.

After you've updated the Cassandra configuration with the new IP addresses, nodes will recognise that a node has a new IP and Cassandra will handle this automatically by re-mapping the new IP to the node's Cassandra host ID. Cheers!

Comment: Understandable, the question is how do i update the ips?

Comment: They're the IPs you configured for `listen_address`, `rpc_address` and the seeds list. Cheers!

Comment: wow, that was easy, thanks for your help!